# Calculate regular values

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

Question: The set in $\mathbb R^3$ of solutions of the equation  $z^2=x^2 + y^2$ is the inverse image of a regular value of a function.
My attempt,I thought about taking a function, $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y,z)= x^2 + y^2 -z^2 +1 $.But this is not valid becouse $1$ is not a regular value,to get $f^{-1}(1)=\{z^2=x^2 + y^2\}$ .Could someone give me and idea , please.

Comment: What do you know about the inverse image of regular values? Is the given set of solutions a manifold?

Comment: the inverse image of a regular value gives you a regular surface.